# What are the Comparable.compareTo interface semantics?

Tags: java, compareto

I don't understand this question. Is it asking the for the method's signature, which is:

```
public int compareTo(Object o)
```

or is it: compareTo() returns negative numbers, 0, and positive numbers respectively indicating whether the calling object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The instructor is looking for that second answer -- what the return value means. That's the semantics ("meaning") of a method. The signature is the "syntax".

Answer (score 3):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantics#Computational_semantics):

> In computer science, the term semantics refers to the meaning of
>   languages, as opposed to their form (syntax). According to Euzenat,
>   semantics "provides the rules for interpreting the syntax which do not
>   provide the meaning directly but constrains the possible
>   interpretations of what is declared." In other words, semantics is
>   about interpretation of an expression. Additionally, the term is
>   applied to certain types of data structures specifically designed and
>   used for representing information content.

Basically, he's asking you what the *meaning* of input to `compareTo(...)` and its output are.

Answer (score 2):

If the target is less than the object that's passed in, the return value is negative; zero if equal; positive if greater than.

It's pretty clear if you read the javadocs for `Comparable`:

```
int compareTo(T o)
```

Compares this object with the specified object for order. Returns a negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less than, equal to, or greater than the specified object.

So

```
int order;
order = "oranges".compareTo("apples"); // greater than zero
order = "oranges".compareTo("oranges"); // zero
order = "oranges".compareTo("plums"); // less than zero
```